# Subsequent loop passes to interpolate population counts are not populating dataframe as intended - logic is incorrect?

Tags: r, dataframe, interpolation, nested-loops

I have a dataframe with 6 variables:

Depr is a factor with 6 levels ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5")

Sex is a factor with 3 levels ("Both sexes", "Female", "Male")

Age is a factor with 19 levels ("00-04", "05-09", "10-14", "15-19",
"20-24", "25- 29", "30-34", "35-39", "40-44", "45-49", "50-54", 
"55-59", "60-64", "65-69", "70-74", "75-79", "80-84", "85+","Total")

GL is a factor (geographical level) with 5 levels ("HPE","KFLA","LGL","ON","Regional")

YR is an integer (year), there are only two - 2011 and 2016 (census years)

And Pop is population count, an integer.

The dataframe is set up in long format where I have population counts for all factor combinations for each of the two years.

```
Depr     Sex           Age      GL       YR        Pop
0        Both sexes   00-04     ON       2011      395     
0        Both sexes   00-04     ON       2016      5550
...
1        Both sexes   00-04     ON       2011      495
1        Both sexes   00-04     ON       2016      3923
```

I want to interpolate for the years in between 2011 and 2016 (2012, 2013, 2014, 2015) for each row in my dataframe so that I get something like this:

```
Depr     Sex           Age      GL       YR        Pop
0        Both sexes   00-04     ON       2011      395     
0        Both sexes   00-04     ON       2012      456
0        Both sexes   00-04     ON       2013      689
0        Both sexes   00-04     ON       2014      2354
0        Both sexes   00-04     ON       2015      3446
0        Both sexes   00-04     ON       2016      5550
```

I have set up nested loops and am using `approx` to do the linear interpolation.

```
#create an empty dataframe to combine the results

fdepr <- data.frame(Depr = factor (levels = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5")), 
                    Sex = factor(levels = c("Both sexes", "Female", "Male")), 
                    Age = factor (levels = c("00-04", "05-09", "10-14", 
                    "15-19", "20-24", "25-29", "30-34", "35-39", "40-44", 
                    "45-49","50-54", "55-59", "60-64", "65-69", "70-74", "75- 
                     79", "80-84", "85+","Total")),
                    GL = factor(levels = c("HPE","KFLA","LGL","ON","Regional")), 
                    YR = integer(), 
                    Pop = integer())


#loops to subset Pop by grouping categories (depr is my original df)

for (i in unique(depr$Depr))
{ 
  for (j in unique(depr$Sex)) 
  {
    for (k in unique(depr$Age)) 
    {
      for (l in unique(depr$GL))  {
      temp <- subset(depr, subset=(Depr==i & Sex==j & Age==k & GL == l),select = c(YR, Pop))
      x <- temp$YR
      y <- temp$Pop
      t <- c(2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016)
      points <- approx(x,y, method = 'linear', xout=t)
      results <- data.frame(Depr=rep(i,6), Sex=rep(j,6), Age=rep(k,6), GL= rep(l,6), YR = points$x, Pop = points$y)
      fdepr <- rbind (fdepr,results)
    } 
  }}}
```

It seems to go through and do the first round fine and populate `results` and `fdepr` as expected, but then I get 
`Error in approx(x, y, method = "linear", xout = t) : 
  need at least two non-NA values to interpolate`

`temp` is empty and so are `x` and `y`. I'm not sure if it's something in the way `fdepr` is defined or if it's the nested loops that are the problem...

I'm not a data scientist so complex logic and programming is not intuitive - any insight is appreciated

Comment: Can you share `depr` or some other example input, as well as the desired output?

Comment: depr has 2964 rows, I'm setting up an empty dataframe to put my interpolated results into

Comment: I've just added something, but I can't put all 2964 combinations, unless I can share the entire dataset here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion creating a new data frame and doing nested for-loops is making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Here I'm using `group_by` and `expand` to get the intermediate years for each of the data groups, then `left_join`ing the original data frame to add the corresponding `Pop` values. After that, you just need to apply `na.approx` to each group of the data, and the data is already grouped from the `expand` part so you can just use `mutate`.

Of course, you could overwrite `Pop` in the `mutate` call instead of creating a new variable, I just did that for illustrative purposes.

```
library(zoo) # for na.approx
library(tidyverse) # for $>%, group_by, expand, left_join, and mutate

depr %>% 
  group_by(Depr, Sex, Age, GL) %>% 
  expand(YR = do.call(seq, as.list(YR))) %>% 
  left_join(depr, names(.)) %>% 
  mutate(Pop_interp = na.approx(Pop))

# # A tibble: 12 x 7
# # Groups:   Depr, Sex, Age, GL [2]
#     Depr Sex   Age   GL       YR   Pop Pop_interp
#    <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int> <int>      <dbl>
#  1     0 Both  00-04 ON     2011   395       395 
#  2     0 Both  00-04 ON     2012    NA      1426 
#  3     0 Both  00-04 ON     2013    NA      2457 
#  4     0 Both  00-04 ON     2014    NA      3488 
#  5     0 Both  00-04 ON     2015    NA      4519 
#  6     0 Both  00-04 ON     2016  5550      5550 
#  7     1 Both  00-04 ON     2011   495       495 
#  8     1 Both  00-04 ON     2012    NA      1181.
#  9     1 Both  00-04 ON     2013    NA      1866.
# 10     1 Both  00-04 ON     2014    NA      2552.
# 11     1 Both  00-04 ON     2015    NA      3237.
# 12     1 Both  00-04 ON     2016  3923      3923
```

Here's the same thing with `data.table` and `magrittr` instead of `tidyverse`

```
library(zoo)
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)

depr[, .(YR = do.call(seq, as.list(YR))), .(Depr, Sex, Age, GL)] %>% 
  .[depr, on = names(.), Pop := i.Pop] %>% 
  .[, Pop_Interp := na.approx(Pop)] %>% 
  print

#     Depr  Sex   Age GL   YR  Pop Pop_Interp
#  1:    0 Both 00-04 ON 2011  395      395.0
#  2:    0 Both 00-04 ON 2012   NA     1426.0
#  3:    0 Both 00-04 ON 2013   NA     2457.0
#  4:    0 Both 00-04 ON 2014   NA     3488.0
#  5:    0 Both 00-04 ON 2015   NA     4519.0
#  6:    0 Both 00-04 ON 2016 5550     5550.0
#  7:    1 Both 00-04 ON 2011  495      495.0
#  8:    1 Both 00-04 ON 2012   NA     1180.6
#  9:    1 Both 00-04 ON 2013   NA     1866.2
# 10:    1 Both 00-04 ON 2014   NA     2551.8
# 11:    1 Both 00-04 ON 2015   NA     3237.4
# 12:    1 Both 00-04 ON 2016 3923     3923.0
```

Input data used

```
depr <- data.table::fread('
Depr     Sex           Age      GL       YR        Pop
0        Both    00-04     ON       2011      395     
0        Both    00-04     ON       2016      5550
1        Both    00-04     ON       2011      495     
1        Both    00-04     ON       2016      3923
', data.table = F)
```

Comment: omg this is so much simpler and cleaner. I would never have known how to code it with dplyr - thank-you! Is there an extrapolation function that I can use within this too? I need denoms for 2010 and 2017..

Comment: I didn't hard code the years to 2011 and 2016 so as long as you have exactly two years in each group it should work fine

Comment: Is extrapolation done differently or can I include it by changing the seq in the expand line somehow?

Comment: Yeah you can change the YR in the expand to be anything if you don’t want it to be a sequence from the first YR in your data to the last. For example, you could change it to expand(YR = 2010:2017) if you want.